# Angular NgResource : Initialize error

Tags: angularjs

i have a weird problem  regarding angular resource. when i try to define it it causes the app to create an error. i dunno but is this the correct style of defining an angular Resource? tIA

main.js

```
'use strict';

require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
    angular: 'libs/angular/angular.min',
    ngResource: 'libs/angular/angular-resource.min'

},

shim: {
    angular: {
        exports: 'angular'
    },

    resource : { deps : ['angular'], 'exports' : 'ngResource'},
  }
  });

    require([
    'jquery',
    'angular',
    //'ngResource',  
    'app',
    'routes',
    ],
    function ($, angular, app,  routes) {// set main controller

$(function(){
    var $html = $('html');
    angular.bootstrap($html, [app['name']]);

    $html.addClass('ng-app');

   });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help out those users who are not familiar with the code above; The code shows RequireJS configuration and initialization structure, and only a small part at the end is the actuall AngularJS code.

You have correctly configured RequireJS to include ngResource before initialization, but you didn't actually tell Angular to use it.
I'm not sure what `app['name']` stands for, but your angular bootstrap call should include the ngResource module:

```
angular.bootstrap($html, ['ngResource']);
```

And, btw, I don't think you need to add the class ('ng-app') at the end.

Comment: hi stewie. thanks but it still not working. what i'm tryi'n to do is implement a requireJS - angularjs version of the PHONECAT tutorial from angular. i got it working on $http but for the ngResource no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

In your callback when all resources are loaded, try to explicitly define the modules and dependancies before bootstrapping, like this:

```
angular.module('fooApp', ['ngResource']); // Module name and list of dependancies.
angular.bootstrap(document, 'fooApp');
```

There is no need to manually add the ng-app class, when this class is used to do bootraping automatically, witch is not what you want. You want to load the applicatiopns module when all scripts are loaded, with the ngResource module as a dependancy.

Hope this helps.